# Problem with adding new shape files to existing cloud project in QGIS for QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have an existing, working QGIS project which I also use in QField. Now I wanted to add a new layer, but something went wrong. I recieved a warning, that I should change the layer properties for QField, but I don't know exactly what to do. I opened the properties and for QField is "Offline editing" (Cloud) and "Copy" (Cable) selected, like in the older layers which are working. What should I Do to solve this?